# Include a cloned npm package that needs building in packages.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I forked a NPM package on github, and would like to use the forked package in my project. Unfortunately, the repository only includes the "uncompiled" sources - you apparently need to run `npm prepublish` on the checked out source to create the "compiled" library in `./lib`.

I can add the cloned repo to my `packages.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "rheostat": "jdmansour/rheostat",
    ...
}
```

But then of course I'd have to run `npm prepublish` (or `build`) for my cloned package. That doesn't work if I go into `node_modules/rheostat`. The reason, I think, is that some `devDependencies` are missing for `rheostat`, e.g. an `airbnb` package. So I'd somehow have to find and add the `devDependencies` of my cloned package to my main project?

I tried the package [npm-git-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-git-install) which is supposed to handle this case, but it didn't work for me. In case it makes any difference, I'm on Windows.

Comment: You can do: `npm install https://github.com/UserName/project.git`. In your package.json you will see:  ` "somePackage": "git+https://github.com/UserName/project.git"`

Comment: @Hosar: Sure, that's what I'm doing. You can actually just use `"somePackage": "UserName/project.git"` if the package is on GitHub. But the problem is that the git sources only contain a `src` folder - the version on npm contains a `lib` folder that is the result of a build step.

Comment: if you cloned, you can verify if `lib` is on **.gitignore**, and just remove it.